# Monitoring and profiling class loaders in java

Tags: java, jvm, profiling, classloader

I am bit newbie to java profiling and i need to diagnose dynamically created class  reloading issue at runtime as it seems class isn't being reloaded. How could i get to know when class get reloaded through some profiling tool?

For problem i am trying  to find solution is to my question below:

[Jackson deserialisation/TypeReference for dynamically loaded pojo class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45518549/jackson-deserialisation-typereference-for-dynamically-loaded-pojo-class)

Answer (score 0):

[JProfiler](https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html) has a class loading probe that you can use for that purpose. In the events view of the class loader probe you can filter for the class name of interest and get the stack trace that causes the reload. To see the stack trace, CPU recording has to be active.

[image]

Disclaimer: My company develops JProfiler.

Comment: Thanks Ingo. That seems to be paid tool although but trial version should work as well. I also found youtube link to your tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e35X3HRad-g
I would check today.